# Which type of Machine Learning is used in robots?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, reference-request, robotics, robots

Which type of Machine Learning is used in robots?
Is it supervised learning or unsupervised learning or Reinforcement learning? Especially the robots that were sent in space?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are lots of types of robots. Many don't use machine learning at all (it's actually quite dangerous to use black-box learners on machines that could cause damage if incorrectly operated), and I'm pretty sure you will also find plenty that use each type of ML depending on purpose. Many will use multiple types of ML, for different sub-tasks withinn the robot. One way to narrow this question down would be to ask about a specific type of robot

Comment: The general question asks for a general answer. There's the risk that this will lead to many different answers, though, which we want to prevent. I think a good answer to this question would be general and maybe provide 1-2 specific examples. Anyway, yes, some robots use ML, in labs, at least. I am pretty of this because I know people that did research on this. Now, I don't really know about the robots for space. So, what I'd suggest is that you at least narrow down the type of robot, although you're already saying "especially the robots that were sent in space", which might still be too broad

Comment: So, please, if you're interested only in robots that were sent into space, edit your question, including the title, to be specific. Otherwise you will get answers for all types of robots and this might be too broad. If you always aks multiple questions, one for each type of robot you have in mind.

Comment: Are you interested only in ML applications in robotics or also want to known about the "engineering way" (pretty much non-ML) of doing robotics?

Comment: I'll just vote to close this because I think this will generate a lot of different answers.

Answer (score 2):

Robotics primarily uses RL and supervised learning. To give examples:

Supervised Learning is used for vision and perception

Reinforcement Learning is used for control

Unsupervised Learning for robotics is less commmon, but I am sure exists.

Source: I work in a robotics lab and use these daily.

Comment: Nice reply. Voted